# Exclude partial duplicates from query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to exclude partial duplicate from my query (MariaDB 5.5.68), for example :

`SELECT num, returned  FROM table  WHERE returned = 1;`

| num(VARCHAR) | returned |
| --- | --- |
| 29.0 | 1 |
| 27.0 | 1 |
| 22.0 | 1 |
| 22.1 | 1 |
| 21.0 | 1 |

In this example I need to exclude `22.0` and only keep `22.1`

I have tried to convert the `num` row as DOUBLE and call `MAX()` but I think I need to do it as a subquery and I cannot get it working.

Comment: Is the logic that you only want the max, in the event that the rounded version of the number is a duplicate?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need the max only if the left side of the number is duplicated. @JNevill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to achieve this:

```
SELECT max(cast(num as decimal(4,2))), returned
FROM table
WHERE returned = 1
GROUP BY cast(num as int), returned
```

In the SELECT clause we cast to decimal for so that `max()` will return the numeric max and not the lexicographical max. In the `GROUP BY` clause we cast to `int` to round the number to integer for proper grouping.